# Open link in new tab, maintaining window.opener

Tags: javascript

The link should open a new tab, WITH reference to window.opener of the original tab. Currently window.opener is set to null.

This has special effect in iOS 12.2 where the window.opener is actually set to null, as opposed to older versions where it's not.

I think that what we need is to keep the new tab in the same browsing-context, but I don't know how.

Comment: I think this question isn't phrased the best.  I'd phrase it as: When opening a new tab via a link, how do we make it so on the new tab, window.opener correctly recognizes the previous tab?  The answer below correct answered that question for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: add rel='opener' to the  tag