# Calling window.opener.location.reload(true); from child window does not reload the parent window on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried debugging and searching online the solution for days now. I am baffled by this bug, the code was working earlier.

contact.php is opening a new child window using button

```
      <form action="sendcontact.php" id="sendcontact" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrftoken" value="ABCD1234">
      </form>   
<button formtarget="_blank" form="sendcontact" name="accountid" id="accountid" value="contact">Submit</button>
```

on the child window sendcontact.php I have a form which self submits to sendcontact.php. After submitting I want to reload the parent window that is contact.php

but

window.opener.location.reload(true); doesn't work.

Console says Null Reference

I have tried

alert(window.opener)

and it produces result

NULL

Also even when the child loads the first time then also alert(window.opener) produces result NULL

Also not working are

window.parent and window.top

Browser: Chrome 11 Latest updated Version 110.0.5481.180 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener: _"Windows opened because of links with a target of `_blank` don't get an opener, unless explicitly requested with `rel=opener`."_ - I would assume that to be the case for windows not opened via links, but by submitting a form, as well. Note: `rel` is not valid on `button`, but on `form`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open link in new tab, maintaining window.opener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607383/open-link-in-new-tab-maintaining-window-opener)

Comment: Many Many Thanks Sir. I spent so much time resolving this. Tried opener, parent, top. Nothing worked. The code was working earlier without rel=opener but it suddently stopped working. Cbroe Nico Thanks a million times sir. Thank you very much.